# What is Positive matrix factorization?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, definition, matrix-decomposition

Recently I encountered the term **Positive matrix factorization (PMF)**. From googling it, I found that it's a *receptor model* which analyses the multivariate data.

First of all, can someone explain to me what is a receptor model?

Secondly, what is **PMF**? How does it work? And can it be used for multivariable analysis of demographic data?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization

Comment: @Glen_b Isn't NMF different from PMF?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization#History suggests not, but maybe the term is used for two different things (which is possible but would mean you need to disambiguate your question)

Comment: Please don't repeat your question in comments.